# Why am i Getting this error? error: invalid operands of types 'int' and 'int(int, int)' to binary 'operator/'

Tags: c++

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
}

int n1, n2;
    cin >> n1 >> n2;
    int lcm =  n1 * n2; //Line 2
    int rem = lcm / gcd;
    cout << gcd(n1, n2) << endl;
    cout << rem << endl;
```

I am getting an Error at line 2 saying "  error: invalid operands of types 'int' and 'int(int, int)' to binary 'operator/' ". I Use Sublime Text Editor to Compile.

Comment: *I Use Sublime Text Editor to Compile* -- Sublime is not a C++ compiler.  g++, clang, Visual C++ -- they are C++ compilers.

Comment: Also note that there is already a [std::gcd](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd) in C++.  Not knowing what the rest of your code looks like, if you are using that `<bits...>` header I see too often, plus `using namespace std;`, your program may not call the `gcd` function you think it will be calling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the error because you cannot divide integers by functions.

Instead of

```
    int rem = lcm / gcd;
```

it seems you wanted to call the function `gcd`.

```
    int rem = lcm / gcd(n1, n2);
```